# How to authorize operation based on user and target element GROUP_ID?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have scenario where I have users, groups and many different elements(models) which are owned by group and have to be accessible only by users from that group with active membership. I have many models belonging to groups.

So basically somehow I need to check that user and target element have the same group_id

How it can be done with Spring Security? 
I was looking for similar scenario but I haven't found even if I am,pretty sure it is quite common usage.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Security provide a complete authorization framework :
http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/el-access.html.

It use annotation like @PreAuthorize to check if the authenticated user is allowed or not to call the method .

Here with the spring method hasRole :

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('USER')")
public void create(Contact contact);
```

If your authorization logic cannot be handled only with default spring methods, you can create your custom implementation :

```
@PreAuthorize("@patientAuth.readObject(authorization,#patientId)")
    public Patient getPatient(Long patientId) {
        Patient patient = patientDao.findOne(patientId);
        if(patient==null) throw new NotFoundException("Patient not found");
        return patient;
    }
```

The method getPatient can only be called if the method patientAuth.readObject return true :